# Creating several classes in Python dynamically

Tags: python, oop

I will appreciate any effort to clarify the following: is there a way in Python to dynamically create one object per class, where several classes are declared? My silly guess can be described as following:

...

## suppose we have some data from db

```
props = dict_cur.fetchall() 
classes_names = []
data = []

for i in props:
    classes_names.append(i['client_name'].title()) 

classes = []
data = []

for i in props:
    data.append(dict(i)) 

for i, d in zip(classes_names, data):
    classes.append(type(i, (object,), dict(**d)))

print classes
#printing list of classes

objects = []
for obj in classes:
objects.append(obj())

for obj in objects:
    print obj.client_name, obj.client_id
```

This is very naive approach and it never lets inherit from created classes in a regular way, just like this:

```
class ClientProcess(Someclient): #Someclient is the name of the created class before


    def __init__(self):
        print "Someclient stuff"
```

The goal is pretty simple: create the objects of several classes, preferably with the properties that are stored in the tables, but at the same time have class declaration for every client which will have specific method implemented that will very from class to class. The initial script that works well and uses Python version of Factory method is not sufficient because it only can process one class(client) a time (based on command-line argument which is client id).

Comment: Why can't you use a class factory again?

Comment: It seems like the problem you're having here is with the magic `type(i, (object,), props)`. Why do you need that in the first place? Why not just store the class objects somewhere, and have your own map from class names to class objects, so you don't need to try to re-generate them on the fly? (As someone said in response to another question: if you don't know how to write `pickle`, just use the `pickle` someone already wrote.)

Comment: Here is my snippet from factory implementation:

class BaseClient(object):
       
    def __new__(cls, *arguments, **keyword):
 for subclass in Baseclient.__subclasses__():
        if subclass.client_id == repr(args['client_id']):
         return super(cls, subclass).__new__(subclass, *arguments, **keyword)
 raise Exception, 'No client is found'
And args is simply list of command line arguments that parsed by argparse module. So script accept clientid and other arguments and instantiating particular class based on following class declaration: 
class Myclient(Client):
 client_id = '111111'

Comment: @abarnert I agree with your "if you don't know how to write pickle, just use the pickle someone already wrote", and that is exactly why I'm asking for help, the code above is just the logic I would like to find in standard library either with metaclasses involved or some OOP patterns that I'm either missing or misunderstanding

Comment: Well, why are you generating class objects on the fly? Is this just a substitute for stashing and retrieving them, or is your class model actually data driven?

Comment: @abarnert It's data driven, and the initial object variables should be determined by data stored in the table, thanks

Comment: @MaliMakh I am still a bit confused as what exactly you are trying to do. So you have a bunch of objects (dynamically created classes?) determined by the data in the table, then?? I am not sure what you are trying to do after that with these objects.. What is client? How are you using the `BaseClient` class?

Comment: The _objects_ being data driven is a whole separate thing from the _class definitions_ being data driven. Is there a reason you need a class generated on the fly, instead of, e.g., just using `dict` objects?

Comment: And meanwhile, on an unrelated topic: you don't have to pay more for variables with maningful names. Those "d" and "i"s as variable names hurt the eyes of anyone looking at this code.

Comment: @KayZhu I have different clients, with different configuration parameters that are stored in the db. Here is a example of some of them: client_id, logfile_directory_path, client_name (there are around 5 of them). Based on those values I would like to have the class built accordingly for every client. Each of them will have the same methods, but different implementation. Let's say I have a check_source method but every client has different source to be checked(locally, ftp, s3amazon), based on the method that is stored in the table. I have perfectly working script, without any classes

Comment: @KayZhu But I was thinking it's more clean and easy to have it written using classes, so if one of the client's method will require some enhancement it would be easy to add later.

Comment: @MaliMakh It seems though your the code you posted does exactly what you are describing.. I didn't quite get what the problem is with that?

Comment: @KayZhu Actually it's not, and specifically the part where I'm trying to create the class that will inherit from one of those that were dynamically built. I'm talking about ClientProcess class

Comment: @MaliMakh So if I understand correctly (sorry it's late for me and maybe I am just not thinking straight..), the problem is that you cannot subclass the dynamically created classes? Then what's wrong with calling `type` again with the dynamically created class as one of the base class?

Comment: @KayZhu I guess I'm the only one who's not thinking straight here:) You're right about subclasses but I'm not following how the next part can be done:( I guess my question more concerned about the actual methods that should be in some place

Comment: @MaliMakh Ok, I think I get what you meant.. I've answered below and hopefully you will find it useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can use the following ways to subclass dynamically created classes:

```
In : classes = []

In : cls_name = 'BaseCls1'

In : classes.append(type(cls_name, (object, ), {'x': 1}))

In : classes[0].x
Out: 1

In : classes[0].__bases__
Out: (object,)

# two ways to create subclass out of BaseCls1

In : class SubCls1(classes[0]):
   :     x = 2
   :
In : SubCls1.x
Out: 2

In : SubCls1.__bases__
Out: (__main__.BaseCls1,)


In : SubCls2 = type('SubCls2', (classes[0],), {'x': 2})

In : SubCls2.x
Out: 2

In : SubCls2.__bases__
Out: (__main__.BaseCls1,)
```

Comment: I'm going to use your version, even though I found another way, many thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

```
class GetConfig(object):

    def __init__(self, client_id):
        self.client_id = client_id
        #construct the query here to get the clients data ...where client_id = self.client_id
        d = {'logfile': 'some_long_path', 'contact_name': 'some_name'}


    class FirstClient(object):

    def __init__(self):
        client_id = '111111111'
        props = GetConfig(client_id)
        #print props.d

    def check_source(self):
        print "Checking FirstClient source"
        return "Something"
        #print props.d

    def check_downl(self):
        print "Checking FirstClient downloaded"


class SecondClient(object):

    def __init__(self):
        client_id = "222222"
        props = GetConfig(client_id)


    def check_source(self):
        print "Checking SecondClient source"

    def check_downl(self):         
        print "Checking SecondClient downloaded"

myfactory = {
"firstclient" : FirstClient,
"secondclient" : SecondClient,
}

for i in myfactory.values():

    i().check_source()
    i().check_downl()
```

Answer (score 0):

collections.namedtuple.  done.
Edit: to elaborate,

```
from collections import namedtuple
rows = dict_cur.fetchall() 
# creates the class Row which is a tuple, but each position argument
# corresponds to the column name in that position
# Row can be instantiated as a tuple and then its elements can be accessed
# by name class attributes 
Row = namedtuple("Row", zip(*dict_cur.description)[0])
objects = [Row(row) for row in rows]

for o in objects:
     print o.client_name, ' is ' , o
```

Comment: This may be an answer, but it could seriously benefit from some explanation.

Comment: @Ajean, added an explanation.   The thing to keep in mind, of course, is that namedtuple returns a class.